# How to use position:relative to different browsers? Or is it not the best way?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm creating static web site and sometimes use position:relative. And when I tested my page on different browsers I got different displays of some elements like 1-2 pixels higher or lower.

How I can solve the problem or I should use something else?

Thought about some `gulp` package but didn't find anything.

Example.

**HTML**:

```
    <p id="search-form-menu">
        <input type="search" name="search-input" placeholder="Поиск">
        <input type="submit" value="">
    </p>
```

**CSS**:

```
   input[type='search'] {
      height: 35px;
      width: 250px;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      position: relative;
      top: -10px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 45px;
   }
   input[type='submit'] {
      height: 35px;
      width: 45px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 0;
      border-left: 3px solid #d1d1d1;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      position: relative;
      top: -10px;
      left: -47px;
      background-image:url("../image/search-loop-2.svg");
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok, did it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `float` style on the submit input?

```
<p id="search-form-menu">
  <input type="search" name="search-input" placeholder="Поиск"/>
  <input type="submit" value=""/>
</p>
```

css

```
p#search-form-menu{
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
}
input[type='search'] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  width: 205px;
  border: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  top:10px;
  border-left: 3px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  background-image:url("../image/search-loop-2.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

created a fiddle and got this to work in chrome and ie.

https://jsfiddle.net/1r8a2u87/2/

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to use positioning here at all.

Just `box-sizing` and `vertical-align`.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #c0ffee;
}
input[type='search'] {
  height: 35px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}
input[type='submit'] {
  height: 35px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-left: 3px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p id="search-form-menu">
  <input type="search" name="search-input" placeholder="Поиск">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</p>
```